# What would happen if all possibly offensive opinions were censured?

Tags: society

In a society dominated by left-wing groups, all possibly inflammatory remarks (Opinions that are susceptible of hurting someone's feelings, including any kind of criticising) are banned as they are deemed offensive.

Things that might happen in my world:

- After an oil spill, people living nearby want to complain about some
  maintenance problems of the facility but it's considered offensive
  for the employees and the company itself. The societal norms consider
  that the employees should not be criticised even if they scrapped the
  job.
- The finance minister ruined the economy with it's poor policies.
  People cannot criticise him because it will hurt his feelings.
- All Media broadcasters choose to omit all evidence that there is a gender gap on salary between men and women. Women might feel bad when hearing this and therefore, it's not allowed to talk about it.
- Medias are also hiding the higher unemployment rates of minority groups because the population might judge them as lazy or feel bad for systematically refusing them during the interviews.

The authorities and corporations will do their best to prevent people from talking about sensitive issues. By doing so, it might frustrate a lot of people that would prefer to speak freely. Furthermore, since it's almost impossible to criticise things that go wrong in the society, this might make these issues worse and lead to societal collapse.

The question is:

**What is the most probable way that bad policy reaches critical mass causing complete societal collapse?**

Comment: Another one of you political loaded questions. Check http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23207/what-would-happen-if-all-politically-correct-sentiments-went-unopposed

Comment: Yes, I decided to start from scratch to comply with the required format.

Comment: Don't do that. I've seen questions that have had roughly 90% thrown out the window, and replaced, then re-opened, with most of the original idea intact. That said, I'm voting to close as primarily opinion-based. If the offensive part wasn't enough.

Comment: Are you asking about politically correct sentiments by today's standards in America, or are you asking about a situation where the concept of political correctness walks, unopposed, making new systems suddenly "politically correct."  If it's the latter, we'd need to have a sense of how politically correct it is to change people's opinion about what is politically correct.

Comment: @Cort Ammon - the intention is that it continues on until the point of failure. So first what is already accepted as politically correct, then what is already being advocated for in obscure corners, and then, if necessary, similar but even more trivial causes.

Comment: This question isn't phrased with enough detail to be answerable except by lots of speculation as to both what you mean, and lots of speculation and opinion about what would happen to an entire imagined world. We also have to imagine what is causing the premise. So this is just going to generate lots of different fantasy answers and ideas, almost all of which would be extremely subjective and imaginary at best, and probably often likely to upset people and inspire arguments and discussion, which we're not really supposed to be doing according to the site design.

Comment: @Dronz - Does it matter what is causing it? What's important is the kind of dogmaticly rationalised policies that are instated, and the implications that they cause to society.

Comment: @Dronz - It's already clear what's causing it anyway. There is a mainstream culture of self censorship which is what I explained up the top. I think you are just inventing objections on the basis of nothing in order to close the question. I think that you are just politically correct yourself and don not want any public discourse regarding yourself.

Comment: @Vincent - the problem I have with your revision is that ALL of the examples you have given are of things THAT POLITICALLY CORRECT PEOPLE WOULD AGREE ARE BAD. Nobody likes oils spills and corporate corruption. All you have done is made the premise of the question politically correct. It's not bad, but it could be more edgy.

Comment: Also note that EVERYTHING that you removed from the question is something that someone else REQUIRED me to include in order to conform to the format.

Comment: I removed nothing, I just rearranged the text. And I can't find "better" examples.

Comment: You should put your question in the sandbox to have it reviewed before posting it here. You'll avoid a lot of frustration this way. http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Comment: @LorryLaurencemcLarry I think you're paranoid. I'm not a PC nutjob. Bite me.  (Not a personal attack, just showing I'm not PC.) My comment was an attempt to help you make a version that wouldn't get closed, and/or to to help you understand why people are going to close these types of questions. It seems to me that one thing missing to be able to even attempt to have an answerable question in SE format, is to have a coherent reason/cause, but I don't find "left-wing" and banning things that are deemed offensive sufficient to have an answer that isn't just making something up.

Answer (score 2):

One day, some particularly clever individual realizes there is a way out of this nightmarish trap.

With great effort and dedication, this individual shifts political correctness to allow for a new behavior to be politically correct.  People fall in line with this new movement, unaware of its final outcome.

It becomes politically correct to be politically incorrect.

Vast political movements begin to quickly capitalize on this process.  They realize that anything which is politically incorrect can suddenly be capitalized on for their own gain.  Everyone jumps on the bandwagon.  Political incorrectness takes over.

And then, one day, they realize it's not holding sway any more.  They've learned how to be so politically incorrect that suddenly, their actions are no longer politically correct enough to be unopposed, and they find their motions dashed upon the shores of public opinion.  Worse, as politically incorrect as they are, nobody can quite find their way back to successfully making politically correct statements to regain their once un-opposed status.

Once nobody remembers how to be politically correct, the unlimited power of political correctness disappears in a poof of logic.

> There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly
>   what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly
>   disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and
>   inexplicable.
>
> There is another theory which states that this has already happened.
>   -Douglas Adams, *Restaurant at the End of the Universe*

Comment: Thanks for engaging with the premise. That was a kind of clever idea.

Comment: You can see the pushback already. Why do you think Donald Trump is so popular on the election campaign circuit? He is saying the things that most people are thinking but feel unable to say.